# Como tratar requisições Ajax com erro de negócio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, java-ee

Procurei pela internet e ainda não achei uma resposta madura o suficiente para um problema.

Tenho uma requisição Ajax e tirando erros lançados pela aplicação como uma possível queda de conexão, por exemplo, eu não quero lançar uma exceção caso eu tenha um erro de negócio.

Por exemplo, o usuário digitar no campo de e-mail um endereço inválido. Eu quero lançar um erro, mas não como erro da requisição para que a função de erro do objeto [ajax do jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) a trate. Não quero algo como erros do tipo HTTP dos intervalos 400 e 500.

Quero retornar o status 200, pois a requisição foi bem sucedida, mas de alguma maneira identificar que houve um erro de negócio.

Vejo muito as pessoas retornando um objeto [JSON](http://www.json.org/) com um atributo booleano de sucesso/falha e caso esteja com falha este mesmo objeto tem um outro objeto JSONArray com as mensagens de erro.

Seria esta a melhor forma de conduzir realmente quando existe um erro de negócio e não de infraestrutura ou da aplicação em si?

Comment: O status code 400 é justamente para representar um erro do cliente. Se o cliente envia um email mal formatado então é um erro do cliente. Conceitualmente, é errado voce tratar como sucesso uma requisição que não atingiu os pré-requisitos necessários e precisou ser abortada. Conceitualmente você não tem um "sucesso". Agora se voce tem alguma limitação e não pode implementar o código de resposta 400 aí é outra história.

Comment: Erros do tipo 400 abrangem erro de negócio? Um usuário que manda uma URL inválida, ou uma String no lugar de um campo numérico e etc? Estes erros devem ser tratados pelo intervalo 400?

Comment: Veja minha reposta abaixo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Não**, esta não é a melhor forma. Você deve retornar um erro 400. O HTTP é um protocolo de aplicação e portanto se você retornar o código 2xx o cliente pode assumir que seu request foi aceito independente de qualquer conteúdo do corpo da resposta.

De [RESTful Web Services Cookbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596801688):

> Um erro comum que alguns serviços web cometem é retornar um status code que reflete sucesso mas incluir uma mensagem no corpo da resposta que descreve uma condição de erro. Ao fazer isso você previne que aplicações baseadas em HTTP detectem erros. Por exemplo o cache (*do browser, ou um proxy reverso por exemplo*) vai armazenar esta resposta como uma resposta bem sucedida e servi-la para os próximos clientes, mesmo quando os clientes fossem capazes de fazer um request correto.

Use códigos 4xx quando o cliente for capaz de corrigir sua requisição e reenviar corretamente, use códigos 5xx quando for um erro do servidor e independente de uma correção no request não fizer sentido reenvia-lo.

*RESPOSTA BASEADA EM https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381520/what-is-the-appropriate-http-status-code-response-for-a-general-unsuccessful-req*

Comment: Alguma dica para qual dentre os status 4xx utilizar?